# Equilibrium of two suspended charge particles

Tags: electrostatics, equilibrium, textbook-erratum

> Two small equally charged spheres, each of mass $m$, are suspended from the same point by silk threads of length $\ell$. The distance between the spheres is $x\ll \ell$. Find the rate $dq/dt$ with which the charge leaks off each sphere if their approach velocity varies as $v=a/\sqrt{x}$, where $a$ is a constant.

This is question 3.3 from IE Irodov's electrostatics part. The solution of this question comes out to be 
$$x^3=\frac{\ell q^2}{2\pi mg\epsilon_0}, \text{  }  \frac{dq}{dt}=\frac32a\sqrt{\frac{2\pi mg\epsilon_0}{\ell}}$$

Now this solution comes under the assumptions that **the charges are always under equilibrium.**

I have following confusion:-

1. If the relative velocity of approach is $v=a/\sqrt{x}$ is a function of $x$, that implies there is acceleration  which means that our assumption of charges being in the equilibrium is wrong.
2. What is the explanation for the assumption of equilibrium condition?

Comment: See [Can spheres leaking charge be assumed to be in equilibrium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72696)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are approaching discharging initially charged pith balls almost at equilibrium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547166/why-are-approaching-discharging-initially-charged-pith-balls-almost-at-equilibri)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct explanation:- Irodov made a mistake 